# Mailapp and keeping attachments in their right format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new and working on a simple function that will 1.save the current spreadsheet under a new name and 2. email a copy of the newly named file to an email address.  My code works but I am having trouble using MailApp to keet the spread sheet in google sheets format.  Here is the code:

```
    function emailPayPeriod() {
  

var Sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var Peter=Sheet.getSheetByName("Peter");
var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("424342423432523534");
var date =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Peter.getRange(2, 2,).getValue()),Sheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MMM-dd-yyyy");
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("324kn24k23b4");
    //SavespreadsheetAs, Save pay periods on google drive based on pay period start name
           
DriveApp.getFileById("893y42ei3ubryu2").makeCopy(date,destFolder); 

//Send Google Sheets File via Email

MailApp.sendEmail("example@gmail.com",'Pay Period', "date",
{
  name: "Title", 
  attachments: [file]

});
}
```

When I get the email with the attachment it is always in .PDF.  The other thing I am trying to figure out is how to pull the file ID from the newly created file and use it in the email function to make sure I am sending the newly named file.  Any pointers on my mistakes are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At Google Docs files (Document, Spreadsheet, Slide and so on), the Google Docs files cannot be directly exported as the same mimeType. It is required to export by converting to other mimeType. So, in your situation, it is required to export the Spreadsheet as other mimeType. For example, those are PDF, XLSX, CSV and so on.
- And, in the current stage, when Google Docs files are sent with `DriveApp.getFileById` as an attachment file of email, the mimeType is automatically converted to PDF. It seems that this is the current specification.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the Spreadsheet is sent by converting to XLSX data. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("324kn24k23b4");
```

#### To:

```
var spreadsheetId = "324kn24k23b4"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=" + spreadsheetId;
var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the Spreadsheet is shared with the user as the writer. In this case, the user can edit the Spreadsheet. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

From:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("324kn24k23b4");
    //SavespreadsheetAs, Save pay periods on google drive based on pay period start name
           
DriveApp.getFileById("893y42ei3ubryu2").makeCopy(date,destFolder); 

//Send Google Sheets File via Email

MailApp.sendEmail("example@gmail.com",'Pay Period', "date",
{
  name: "Title", 
  attachments: [file]

});
```

To:

```
var userEmail = "example@gmail.com";
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("324kn24k23b4");
Drive.Permissions.insert({role: "writer", type: "user", value: userEmail}, file.getId(), {sendNotificationEmails: false});
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 'Pay Period', "date" + "\n" + file.getUrl(), { name: "Title" });
```

#### Note:

- About your following 2nd question,

  > The other thing I am trying to figure out is how to pull the file ID from the newly created file and use it in the email function to make sure I am sending the newly named file.

  - In this case, you can retrieve the file ID of the copied file and you can add the file ID to the email using the following script.

    ```
      const fileId = DriveApp.getFileById("893y42ei3ubryu2").makeCopy(date,destFolder).getId();
      MailApp.sendEmail("example@gmail.com", 'Pay Period', "date" + "\n" + fileId, { name: "Title", attachments: [file] });
    ```

#### References:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)

  - The endpoint for exporting to XLSX data is from the method of "Files: get".
- [Permissions: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert)

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed explanation! Thank you for taking the time to explain things to me as a beginner.

Comment: @DataCrisis Thank you for replying. Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.